# how to nth element of set

Tags: c++, set

how to get the value of Nth element of set directly

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  set<int> a;
  a.insert(1);
  a.insert(2);
  a.insert(3);
  a.insert(4);
  a.insert(5);
  cout << ans[4] << endl;
}
```

I want '4' as an output without iterating over a loop 4 times with iterator.
Is there a pre-defined way to get nth element of a set.

" error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::set’ and ‘int’)"

Comment: `std::advance` or `std::next` can be used hide that loop. `std::set` is not random accessible, so you have to walk through the elements.